# Поиск параметра в списке с помощью regexp

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я не силен регулярных выражениях....

Помогите составить регулярку для поиска в списке строк!

Есть набор строк:

```
mbcli
port=ttyS0
parity=odd
```

надо найти строку начинающуюся с "port="

Пытался написать что то типа ^port\=* - не дает результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так:
`^port=[\s\S]+?$`
Должно работать.

Update:

`^` - начало строки.

`port=` - фиксированная часть.

`[\s\S]` - Любые символы `\s` - пробелы, переносы строк и т.д. `\S` - Не пустые символы, буквы, цифры, знаки препинания.

`+` - встречающиеся минимум 1 раз. Если у вас возможна ситуация, что значение для port не указано, но строку найти надо - воспользуйтесь `*`.

`?` - non greedy pattern - заставляет искать самую короткую последовательность соответствующую шаблону.

`$` - конец строки.

В общем этот шаблон возьмет строку начинающуюся с port= и заканчивающуюся концом строки.

Comment: а можно пояснить?

Comment: `^` - начало строки.
`port=` - фиксированная часть.
`[\s\S]` - Любые символы \s - пробелы, переносы строк и т.д. \S - Не пустые символы, буквы, цифры, знаки препинания.
`+` - встречающиеся минимум 1 раз.
`?` - non greedy pattern - заставляет искать самую короткую последовательность соответствующую шаблону.
`$` - конец строки.

В общем этот шаблон возьмет строку начинающуюся с port= и заканчивающуюся концом строки.

Comment: это то понятно...

Comment: а дальше? что за набор?

Comment: @КонстантинФомин, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить так

```
  ^port=[\w\d]+
```

^ - начало строки, 
port= - фиксированная часть, 
[\w\d] - \w - любая буква, \d - любая цифра, + - встречающиеся минимум 1 раз

Comment: а можно пояснить?

Comment: Вариант подходит, если строка порта буквенно-цифровая, но в природе есть варианты microsoft-ds, whois++, z39.50 и т.д. А если в строке будет еще и опечатка, то можно получить непредсказуемый результат, который не получится провалидировать, так как выражение найдет только часть строки.